# use jquery to add to a table through inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I have been searching and searching for an answer to this. I may not be using the right search criteria and would appreciate your help.

I am very new to programming. This may be a very simple solution... I cannot seem to find it on the site. Right now I am working on getting a two element array to display in a table after taking input from the user. Basically taking in two numbers given by the user and then putting them in separate columns in the table.

At this point I can get them to go up in to the table, however I cannot get them to be in their own row each time I add new ones. They just get added to the same row.

Thanks so much for your help.

Here is my Java/Jquery

```
// this one adds new data to the row that I create.
            var $newTd = $("<td>");

            var $smallArrayPartOne = $("<td>").text($firstnumber);
            var $smallArrayPartTwo = $("<td>").text($secondnumber);


            // This section creates my two different arrays
            smallArray.push($firstnumber);
            smallArray.push($secondnumber);
            totalArray.push(smallArray);


            // This is to get the numbers under the inputs
            print = $("<p>").text(sum);
            $(".totals").prepend(print);

            // this clears the input boxes after I have clicked the button
            $(".number-input input").val("");
            $(".other-number input").val("");

            // This is how I get the array in to the table. This gets it to show up right. It is not getting the html to show up how I would like it though.
            $(".theTable").append($smallArrayPartOne);
            $(".theTable").append($smallArrayPartTwo);


            // I added this because when it was not there it would add data on to one row instead of creating a new one. Hopefully that gets it to work.
```

and the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <main>
        <table style="width:50%" border="1" text-align="center" class = "theTable">
             <tr>
                <th>First Number</th>
                <th>Second Number</th> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Test number</td>
                <td>Second Test</td> 
              </tr>
        </table>
        </br>
        </br>
        <section class="number-input">
        <input type="integer">
        </section>
        </br>
        </br>
        <section class="other-number">
        <input type="integer">
        <button>+</button></br>
        </br>
        <section class="addition">
        <button class="first">total number one</button>
        <button class="second">total number two</button>
        </section>

        <section class="totals">
        </section>  

    </main>

    <footer>
    </footer>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a row is TR not TD ... you have nowhere in your code a new TR ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a row is TR not TD ... you have nowhere in your code a new TR ... 
try this

```
  $(".theTable").append($('<tr>').append($smallArrayPartOne));
```